# Can't Append to a text file

Tags: python, text

I was working on a password manager code when I stumbled upon this problem:

```
while True:
    los = input('Login or Sign Up (l or s): ').lower()

    if los == 'l':
        username = input("Username: ")
        with open('database.txt', 'r') as f:
            for line in f.readlines():
                rn, rp = line.split(" | ")
                if rn == username:
                    print("Account Found!")
                    while True:
                        password = input("Password: ")
                        if password == rp:
                            print("Logged In")
                            break
                        else:
                            print("Wrong Password.")
                            continue
                    main(rn, rp)
                else:
                    print("Account not Found.")

    elif los == 's':
        username = input("Username: ")
        password = input("Password: ")
        print("Data Entered.")
        with open('database.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.append(username, "|", password + '\n')
        with open(username+'.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write('')
        main(username, password)

    else:
        print("That is Invalid. Try again.")
        continue
```

Whenever I "Sign Up" and enter the credentials, it presents me with an error showing I cannot append to a text file.

Thanks in advance for the help1

Comment: There's no `.append()` for files. Try `.write()`!

Comment: Welcome to SO. When you ask a question, you should be precise with the problem/error description. It does not say that you can't append to a file, but gives you a runtime error `AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'append'`. And if you get such an error, you should tell us exactly that. It does not mean that you can't append a file, it just tells you that you try to call a function that does not exist. Please read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

In `with open('database.txt', 'a')` `'a'` stands for 'append', so `.write()` will do the trick! Whereas if you use `'w'`, `.write()` will overwrite it instead.

Comment: This answer as currently written implies that in the `open(..., 'w')` case preexisting content isn't lost until a `write()` is performed -- an implication that is not in fact true.